# Why is there less sound volume in Ubuntu / Linux Mint when compared to Windows?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Sound is much lower in Ubuntu / Linux Mint when compared to that of Windows 7. Am I supposed to increase the volume above 100%?[image: volume slider]

I am using the Realtek inbuilt audio; NOT the Creative Soundblaster.

```
melvin@melvin-mint-pc ~ $ LC_ALL=C cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#* | LC_ALL=C fgrep --before-context=4 --after-context=1 "Subsystem Id"
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0887
Subsystem Id: 0x10438445
Revision Id: 0x100302
--
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x1002aa01
Subsystem Id: 0x00aa0100
Revision Id: 0x100300
melvin@melvin-mint-pc ~ $ LC_ALL=C lspci -vvnn | LC_ALL=C fgrep --after-context=1 "Audio device"
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8445]
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1002:aab0]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device [174b:aab0]
```

Comment: this is because Windows usually gets driver from vendor which make your sound hardware which in my opinion are the best and most appropriate. while on Linux we usually use one driver for many (almost all) kinds of sound hardware, getting the best out of all is not possible

Comment: It gets worse on my Lenovo laptop, which uses Conexant audio with Dolby Digital. Nothing like Dolby on Linux, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal type:

```
alsamixer
```

and set master volume louder

Comment: It's already at 100%...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ICeaEHF.png

Comment: have you tried pavucontrol ? - PulseAudio Volume Control

Comment: That's also at 100%. But I can boost the volume beyond 100, if that is advisable.

Comment: Beyond 100% is beyond 0db amplification. You can overdrive sound. Hoverer if source is quiet you can use this additional amplification

Comment: Sounds good for me. Literally.

Comment: So that should solve the sound issue...

Comment: pavucontrol works on mint over 100%, but after using the system vol-down then vol-up - it won't go above 100% again.  Only pavucontrol app can do it again.  Would be better to have a fully integrated solution that increases system-wide available max.  Also - found that Mint 18 "sound" also can go above 100%, so no need for an extra application - thus uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `hdajackretask` GUI tool. If you're using Ubuntu it's in the `alsa-tools-gui` package.
Find your port, tick `Override` and choose `Headphone`, apply.

Surprisingly I got my volume back. Finally. Yay! (I'm using headphones).
Sadly almost nobody recommends to try this tool.

Comment: Please stop copy-pasting the same answer all over the site.  Downvoted your other answers and leaving this as is.

Comment: @Fabby Same question - same answer. "Flag" action requires 15 points of rating - I didn't have that much. This is a hard to find solution, if I didn't copy-paste it, it would have no chance and get lost in a bunch of question duplicates ¯_(ツ)_⁄¯